# Vista backup zip file manual recovery

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-restore

I backed up my vista comp and installed win 7. I have Backtrack 5 and Debian backed up. I found them zipped on my external drive (I use Winrar) and copied them 2 my Desktop. They are ISO's and each are in 6 to 7 zip files.  Is there a way to get them back to a single ISO without doing a full backup? Was just trying to avoid downloading them again cause they  are quite big files. Any help is much thanked!!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason WinRAR won't work to decompress them into a single ISO?

If WinRAR isn't working, have you tried [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)?

If neither of these work, are there specific error messages you are receiving when you attempt to decompress them?

UPDATED for OP response:

Ok, remove your WinRAR trial version. No need to keep a trial version when you can get a full blown and very capable alternative for free. Go get yourself 7zip from the link above and then report back when done.

Now, pretty much the only thing you'll need to do is place all 8 .zip segments in the same directory. Then right-click on the first one and select 7-zip and Extract to (wherever you want to extract to).

If the zip file segments are real segments that belong to each other, you'll get a nice big single unzipped resulting file, ISO or whatever it is supposed to be.

Comment: I might not know how. I open them in winrar trial version and navigate to them and drag them to a new folder. I archived all 8 zip files and tried to unzip it and it just gave me all 8 separate zips again. I tried to use imgburn because they show as iso's just in 199Mb increments but they were not as one which should be about 4 Gigs...Not sure if my info answers you Q..

Comment: Awesome...cant do it now but will post back when i can. thanks so much!!